# Where can I find a good detailed tutorial on the lifecycle of a page request?

Tags: asp.net, lifecycle

A good detailed tutorial on the lifecycle of a page request.

I've read up on the ASP.NET page lifecycle, I am talking about things that happened before the .NET process starts to handle the request.

i.e. domain typed into browser, DNS mapping? etc.

Comment: +1 +star, provided someone can provide a solid workflow or process map of the lifecycle

Answer (score 2):

For Quick Reference:

I use the following chart all the time, it is hanging by my desk:
http://blog.krisvandermast.com/ASPNET20PageLifeCycle.aspx

As well as a detailed version of each stage:
http://john-sheehan.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/aspnet-life-cycles-events.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I found [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx) really interesting, hope you like it too.

Answer (score 1):

I would read [ASP.NET Application Life Cycle Overview for IIS 5.0 and 6.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178473.aspx):

> Within ASP.NET, several processing
>   steps must occur for an ASP.NET
>   application to be initialized and
>   process requests. Additionally,
>   ASP.NET is only one piece of the Web
>   server architecture that services
>   requests made by browsers. It is
>   important for you to understand the
>   application life cycle so that you can
>   write code at the appropriate life
>   cycle stage for the effect you intend.