# How ASP.NET page works?

Tags: asp.net, iis

I like to know how ASP.net page works(page lifecyle starting from IIS to weberver process request())

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/820342/where-can-i-find-a-good-detailed-tutorial-on-the-lifecycle-of-a-page-request

Answer (score 1):

[Here's the lifecycle in gory detail.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)  Good cheat sheet too ([PDF link](http://john-sheehan.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/aspnet-life-cycles-events.pdf)).

Answer (score 1):

That is fully documented by MSDN:

[ASP.NET Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227435.aspx)

[ASP.NET Page Life Cycle Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx)